# Material Design vs. Angular-Material vs. CSS-Frameworks

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I started developing [my first website](https://vica.one) about 6 months ago and primarily used [bulma](https://bulma.io/documentation) as a css framework for making my life easier when it comes to styling. After using Angular-Material Components I now discovered the Material Design principles and really like them. Since there is a "redesign" planned for the website I would like to use this to use material design for the whole front end. I read a lot on material.io and material.angular.ui but I must say that I am very confused about how to actually use this design method for "simple" things that don't include their components. In bulma there is a css-selector for heading like `<h1 class="is-title is-1">` and that's all I needed to do for having a nice heading.

1. How do I achieve these things in material? Do I need bootstrap-material for that or must I write my own css classes?
2. Is there a way to defined my theme ONCE and it works for material design AND angular material?

I basically have trouble finding a bulma-like documentation. It seems I am on the wrong path. If someone can provide a good blog post about my issue or explain a little bit what I REALLY need - that would be awesome.

Thank you a lot :)

Comment: https://material.angular.io/guide/typography

Comment: https://material.io/design/material-theming/overview.html

Answer (score 1):

Angular material and material design basically the same. Material design is abstract for mobile and web. Angular material is implemented for Angular. So if you use "Angular material" you are using "Material design".

Angular material concept predefined design with components and you can override style with non-capsule css.

So if you use `<mat-icon>` and icon name can be search from here: https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline

Comment: Angular material may not be as up-to-date as material. These projects lives separately even if they are both maintained by Google.